# mypy differences in isinstance and issubclass from python 3.5 to 3.6 in parameterized generics

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing, mypy

Before I upgraded to python 3.6 from python 3.5 this worked:

```
import typing
issubclass(list, typing.List[int])  # returns True
isinstance([1, 2 ,3], typing.List[int]) # returns True
```

now in python 3.6 both of these raise the following exception:

```
TypeError: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks
```

Is this new intended behavior or a bug? If it is intended how can I perform the checks the code above is doing in python 3.6?

Comment: I don't think they ever did check the element types, so `["a", "b", "c"]` would have passed `isinstance(["a", "b", "c"], typing.List[int])`. The implemented semantics of the check weren't useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is intentional, you shouldn't be mixing classes with types as defined in `typing`, at least, that's the gist of it from what I've understood. A great deal of discussion for this is contained in the issue [`#136 Kill __subclasscheck__`](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/136) which also introduced this change. The [commit message](https://github.com/python/typing/commit/7baf6fe2a6d96ab09c807aac174650baa35d15dd) also references how the `isinstance`/`subclass` checks will raise `TypeError`s:

> Using `isinstance()` or `issubclass()` raises `TypeError` for almost everything. There are exceptions: [...]

You *can* compare without specifying the contained types for the generic types, i.e:

```
isinstance(list, typing.List[int])
```

but that's the best you can do afaik.

Comment: Thanks, informative link. So there is no way do type validation using the types from typing? For example if I wanted to ensure the inputs to a function are consistent with the type annotation of the function before launching a lengthy processing routine? I know this can be done statically with mypy but I am running into a case were it can only be done dynamically within the python code itself.  There was some talk of this in the PR but I didn't see that it actually went anywhere.

Comment: by the way, `isinstance(list, typing.List[int])` still raises a TypeError

Comment: edited your answer so the code is consistent with what you described in the text.

Comment: Wow... How to take a language and make it less useful/

Comment: Yes, your example used to work in 3.6, but in 3.7 you get `TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have better type safety in python your options are somewhat limited. A technique I have employed is to subclass **list** or **dict** without overriding any properties, methods etc.

```
class ListInts(list):
    pass

new_obj = ListInts()
new_obj += [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(isinstance(new_obj, ListInts)
```