# Validating detailed types in python dataclasses

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, python-dataclasses

Python 3.7 was released a while ago, and I wanted to test some of the fancy new `dataclass`+typing features. Getting hints to work right is easy enough, with both native types and those from the `typing` module:

```
>>> import dataclasses
>>> import typing as ty
>>> 
... @dataclasses.dataclass
... class Structure:
...     a_str: str
...     a_str_list: ty.List[str]
...
>>> my_struct = Structure(a_str='test', a_str_list=['t', 'e', 's', 't'])
>>> my_struct.a_str_list[0].  # IDE suggests all the string methods :)
```

But one other thing that I wanted to try was forcing the type hints as conditions during runtime, i.e. it should not be possible for a `dataclass` with incorrect types to exist. It can be implemented nicely with [`__post_init__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#post-init-processing):

```
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass
... class Structure:
...     a_str: str
...     a_str_list: ty.List[str]
...     
...     def validate(self):
...         ret = True
...         for field_name, field_def in self.__dataclass_fields__.items():
...             actual_type = type(getattr(self, field_name))
...             if actual_type != field_def.type:
...                 print(f"\t{field_name}: '{actual_type}' instead of '{field_def.type}'")
...                 ret = False
...         return ret
...     
...     def __post_init__(self):
...         if not self.validate():
...             raise ValueError('Wrong types')
```

This kind of `validate` function works for native types and custom classes, but not those specified by the `typing` module:

```
>>> my_struct = Structure(a_str='test', a_str_list=['t', 'e', 's', 't'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  a_str_list: '<class 'list'>' instead of 'typing.List[str]'
  ValueError: Wrong types
```

Is there a better approach to validate an untyped list with a `typing`-typed one? Preferably one that doesn't include checking the types of all elements in any `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, or `set` that is a `dataclass`' attribute.

---

Revisiting this question after a couple of years, I've now moved to use [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) in cases where I want to validate classes that I'd normally just define a dataclass for. I'll leave my mark with the currently accepted answer though, since it correctly answers the original question and has outstanding educational value.

Comment: The obvious solution would be `if not isinstance(actual_type, field_def.type):`... but of course the obvious solution doesn't work: `TypeError: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks`.

Comment: That made me find `ty.List.__origin__` though, which gives `<class 'list'>`. That won't let me check the inner type, but at least it won't crash on me any more

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42027923/1222951) similar question, but it doesn't really have a solution. If you're down for checking the type manually, you'll find these two links useful: [What's the correct way to check if an object is a typing.Generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49171189) and [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/48572831)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Those were some really interesting reads!

Comment: This is a lost cause. Trying to enforce this would encur prohibative runtime costs. What is the list is a million items long? Do you want to iterate over every item checking its type? What if I do `struct.a_str_list[24] = 1` -- you'd have no way of knowing. You'd have to write a specialised subclass of list  that introspects its items and only allow that class rather than `list` in your structure. This is a lot fo runtime overhead and more easily prevented by using guards at the API level, and type annotations with linting elsewhere.

Comment: @Dunes That's what I was afraid of, or rather, I wouldn't have known how to work around my problem while avoiding the pitfalls you describe. Lost cause it is then, plus then bandaid of learning `__origin__` at least lets me use `typing`.

Comment: Related: [How do I check if a value matches a type in python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55503673)

Comment: I'll just add for future adventurers, that you need to avoid using `from __future__ import annotations` if you want typing to work as described in accepted answer.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Instead of checking for type equality, you should use `isinstance`. But you cannot use a parametrized generic type (`typing.List[int]`) to do so, you must use the "generic" version (`typing.List`). So you will be able to check for the container type but not the contained types. Parametrized generic types define an `__origin__` attribute that you can use for that.

Contrary to Python 3.6, in Python 3.7 most type hints have a useful `__origin__` attribute. Compare:

```
# Python 3.6
>>> import typing
>>> typing.List.__origin__
>>> typing.List[int].__origin__
typing.List
```

and

```
# Python 3.7
>>> import typing
>>> typing.List.__origin__
<class 'list'>
>>> typing.List[int].__origin__
<class 'list'>
```

Python 3.8 introduce even better support with the [`typing.get_origin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin) introspection function:

```
# Python 3.8
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_origin(typing.List)
<class 'list'>
>>> typing.get_origin(typing.List[int])
<class 'list'>
```

Notable exceptions being `typing.Any`, `typing.Union` and `typing.ClassVar`… Well, anything that is a `typing._SpecialForm` does not define `__origin__`. Fortunately:

```
>>> isinstance(typing.Union, typing._SpecialForm)
True
>>> isinstance(typing.Union[int, str], typing._SpecialForm)
False
>>> typing.get_origin(typing.Union[int, str])
typing.Union
```

But parametrized types define an `__args__` attribute that store their parameters as a tuple; Python 3.8 introduce the [`typing.get_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) function to retrieve them:

```
# Python 3.7
>>> typing.Union[int, str].__args__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)

# Python 3.8
>>> typing.get_args(typing.Union[int, str])
(<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)
```

So we can improve type checking a bit:

```
for field_name, field_def in self.__dataclass_fields__.items():
    if isinstance(field_def.type, typing._SpecialForm):
        # No check for typing.Any, typing.Union, typing.ClassVar (without parameters)
        continue
    try:
        actual_type = field_def.type.__origin__
    except AttributeError:
        # In case of non-typing types (such as <class 'int'>, for instance)
        actual_type = field_def.type
    # In Python 3.8 one would replace the try/except with
    # actual_type = typing.get_origin(field_def.type) or field_def.type
    if isinstance(actual_type, typing._SpecialForm):
        # case of typing.Union[…] or typing.ClassVar[…]
        actual_type = field_def.type.__args__

    actual_value = getattr(self, field_name)
    if not isinstance(actual_value, actual_type):
        print(f"\t{field_name}: '{type(actual_value)}' instead of '{field_def.type}'")
        ret = False
```

This is not perfect as it won't account for `typing.ClassVar[typing.Union[int, str]]` or `typing.Optional[typing.List[int]]` for instance, but it should get things started.

---

Next is the way to apply this check.

Instead of using `__post_init__`, I would go the decorator route: this could be used on anything with type hints, not only `dataclasses`:

```
import inspect
import typing
from contextlib import suppress
from functools import wraps


def enforce_types(callable):
    spec = inspect.getfullargspec(callable)

    def check_types(*args, **kwargs):
        parameters = dict(zip(spec.args, args))
        parameters.update(kwargs)
        for name, value in parameters.items():
            with suppress(KeyError):  # Assume un-annotated parameters can be any type
                type_hint = spec.annotations[name]
                if isinstance(type_hint, typing._SpecialForm):
                    # No check for typing.Any, typing.Union, typing.ClassVar (without parameters)
                    continue
                try:
                    actual_type = type_hint.__origin__
                except AttributeError:
                    # In case of non-typing types (such as <class 'int'>, for instance)
                    actual_type = type_hint
                # In Python 3.8 one would replace the try/except with
                # actual_type = typing.get_origin(type_hint) or type_hint
                if isinstance(actual_type, typing._SpecialForm):
                    # case of typing.Union[…] or typing.ClassVar[…]
                    actual_type = type_hint.__args__

                if not isinstance(value, actual_type):
                    raise TypeError('Unexpected type for \'{}\' (expected {} but found {})'.format(name, type_hint, type(value)))

    def decorate(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            check_types(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    if inspect.isclass(callable):
        callable.__init__ = decorate(callable.__init__)
        return callable

    return decorate(callable)
```

Usage being:

```
@enforce_types
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

@enforce_types
def foo(bar: typing.Union[int, str]):
    pass
```

Appart from validating some type hints as suggested in the previous section, this approach still have some drawbacks:

- type hints using strings (`class Foo: def __init__(self: 'Foo'): pass`) are not taken into account by `inspect.getfullargspec`: you may want to use [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) and [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) instead;
- a default value which is not the appropriate type is not validated:

  ```
   @enforce_type
   def foo(bar: int = None):
       pass

   foo()
  ```

  does not raise any `TypeError`. You may want to use [`inspect.Signature.bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind) in conjuction with [`inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments.apply_defaults) if you want to account for that (and thus forcing you to define `def foo(bar: typing.Optional[int] = None)`);
- variable number of arguments can't be validated as you would have to define something like `def foo(*args: typing.Sequence, **kwargs: typing.Mapping)` and, as said at the beginning, we can only validate containers and not contained objects.

---

#### Update

After this answer got some popularity and a [library](https://pypi.org/project/enforce-typing/) heavily inspired by it got released, the need to lift the shortcomings mentioned above is becoming a reality. So I played a bit more with the `typing` module and will propose a few findings and a new approach here.

For starter, `typing` is doing a great job in finding when an argument is optional:

```
>>> def foo(a: int, b: str, c: typing.List[str] = None):
...   pass
... 
>>> typing.get_type_hints(foo)
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'str'>, 'c': typing.Union[typing.List[str], NoneType]}
```

This is pretty neat and definitely an improvement over `inspect.getfullargspec`, so better use that instead as it can also properly handle strings as type hints. But `typing.get_type_hints` will bail out for other kind of default values:

```
>>> def foo(a: int, b: str, c: typing.List[str] = 3):
...   pass
... 
>>> typing.get_type_hints(foo)
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'str'>, 'c': typing.List[str]}
```

So you may still need extra strict checking, even though such cases feels very fishy.

Next is the case of `typing` hints used as arguments for `typing._SpecialForm`, such as `typing.Optional[typing.List[str]]` or `typing.Final[typing.Union[typing.Sequence, typing.Mapping]]`. Since the `__args__` of these `typing._SpecialForm`s is always a tuple, it is possible to recursively find the `__origin__` of the hints contained in that tuple. Combined with the above checks, we will then need to filter any `typing._SpecialForm` left.

Proposed improvements:

```
import inspect
import typing
from functools import wraps


def _find_type_origin(type_hint):
    if isinstance(type_hint, typing._SpecialForm):
        # case of typing.Any, typing.ClassVar, typing.Final, typing.Literal,
        # typing.NoReturn, typing.Optional, or typing.Union without parameters
        return

    actual_type = typing.get_origin(type_hint) or type_hint  # requires Python 3.8
    if isinstance(actual_type, typing._SpecialForm):
        # case of typing.Union[…] or typing.ClassVar[…] or …
        for origins in map(_find_type_origin, typing.get_args(type_hint)):
            yield from origins
    else:
        yield actual_type


def _check_types(parameters, hints):
    for name, value in parameters.items():
        type_hint = hints.get(name, typing.Any)
        actual_types = tuple(_find_type_origin(type_hint))
        if actual_types and not isinstance(value, actual_types):
            raise TypeError(
                    f"Expected type '{type_hint}' for argument '{name}'"
                    f" but received type '{type(value)}' instead"
            )


def enforce_types(callable):
    def decorate(func):
        hints = typing.get_type_hints(func)
        signature = inspect.signature(func)

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            parameters = dict(zip(signature.parameters, args))
            parameters.update(kwargs)
            _check_types(parameters, hints)

            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    if inspect.isclass(callable):
        callable.__init__ = decorate(callable.__init__)
        return callable

    return decorate(callable)


def enforce_strict_types(callable):
    def decorate(func):
        hints = typing.get_type_hints(func)
        signature = inspect.signature(func)

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound = signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            bound.apply_defaults()
            parameters = dict(zip(signature.parameters, bound.args))
            parameters.update(bound.kwargs)
            _check_types(parameters, hints)

            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    if inspect.isclass(callable):
        callable.__init__ = decorate(callable.__init__)
        return callable

    return decorate(callable)
```

---

<sub>Thanks to [@Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/aran-fey) that helped me improve this answer.</sub>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172211/discussion-between-mathias-ettinger-and-aran-fey).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer! =) I finally got around to understand and test it, and it solved my problems as well as taught me a lot about `typing`.

Comment: There is a [library](https://pypi.org/project/enforce-typing/) inspired by this answer available.

Comment: @301_Moved_Permanently the library indicated by @Jundiaius above suffers from all the shortcomings you mention in your answer. Notably, checking `Optional[List[str]]` results in an error. Would you be interested to contribute to that library to cover the corner cases? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Philipp You made me contribute to SO again after I wanted to depart with it, shame on you ;)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. ....helped me hugely!  My question is the above will handle cases of `Optional[List[str]]` by return a type of `'list'`.  But in this case a list of anything will match.  ...So is there a way (module?) to also check the contents of the list (in my example, are they all strings) against the hint, with the exception of moving to pydantic or equivalent?

Comment: @Richard As stated at the beginning of the answer, I'm not focusing on validating types inside of collections. As hinted by [Dunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563546/validating-detailed-types-in-python-dataclasses/50622643#comment88167102_50563546), this is hard to do right; especially the case of generators : should we exhaust them for type-checking? How to store the values? What if we don't use evrything? What if it is infifnite? `pydantic` allows such checks for simple cases but I don't think you'll find a generic answer anywhere.

Comment: Note to future adventurers - if you have `from __future__ import annotations` then types will not work the way as it's described in this answer.

Answer (score 67):

Just found this question.

[pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io) can do full type validation for dataclasses out of the box. (admission: I built pydantic)

Just use pydantic's version of the decorator, the resulting dataclass is completely vanilla.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User:
    id: int
    name: str = 'John Doe'
    signup_ts: datetime = None

print(User(id=42, signup_ts='2032-06-21T12:00'))
"""
User(id=42, name='John Doe', signup_ts=datetime.datetime(2032, 6, 21, 12, 0))
"""

User(id='not int', signup_ts='2032-06-21T12:00')
```

The last line will give:

```
    ...
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error
id
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details how to use `pydantic`? Maybe with code examples.

Comment: The question is talking typinh with generics, does pydantic support it? Does it validate `typing.List[str]` correctly? Thanks :)

Comment: @SColvin ....I'd second Marco's question above!  Will it also handle `Optional[List[str]]` correctly (ie either None or a list of only strings)?

Answer (score 2):

I created a tiny Python library for this purpose: https://github.com/tamuhey/dataclass_utils

This library can be applied for such dataclass that holds another dataclass (nested dataclass), and nested container type (like `Tuple[List[Dict...`)

Comment: That simple library is the only one that seems to be working for me. I think there are some cases it still doesn't get (like `x:MyEnum = ''`), but for the rest it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

For typing aliases, you must separately check the annotation.
I did like this:
https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc