# Check if type is a list

Tags: python, python-3.6, typing

I have some types (coming from `inspect.signature` -> `inspect.Parameter`) and I'd like to check if they are lists or not. My current solution works but is very ugly, see minimal example below:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Type, TypeVar

IntList = List[int]
StrList = List[str]
IntStrDict = Dict[int, str]

TypeT = TypeVar('TypeT')

# todo: Solve without using string representation of type
def is_list_type(the_type: Type[TypeT]) -> bool:
    return str(the_type)[:11] == 'typing.List'

assert not is_list_type(IntStrDict)
assert not is_list_type(int)
assert not is_list_type(str)
assert is_list_type(IntList)
assert is_list_type(StrList)
```

What would be the correct way to check if a type is a `List`?

(I'm using Python 3.6 and the code should survive a check with `mypy --strict`.)

Comment: Why don't just: `if type(...) is list: `?

Comment: @Austin because that won't working with the `typing` type aliases

Comment: Provisionally, `alias.__origin__` seems to be `list` type. I'm trying to find some documentation of this dunder attribute though... EDIT: seems to be only there for 3.7.

Comment: or rather, in 3.6 `List.__origin__`  returns `None`, and while `List[T]` will return `typing.List`, however, both of these seem to return `list` in Python 3.7... ugh

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563546/validating-detailed-types-in-python-dataclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `issubclass` to check types like this:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Type, TypeVar

IntList = List[int]
StrList = List[str]
IntStrDict = Dict[int, str]

TypeT = TypeVar('TypeT')

# todo: Solve without using string representation of type
def is_list_type(the_type: Type[TypeT]) -> bool:
    return issubclass(the_type, List)

assert not is_list_type(IntStrDict)
assert not is_list_type(int)
assert not is_list_type(str)
assert is_list_type(IntList)
assert is_list_type(StrList)
```