# Force type conversion in python dataclass __init__ method

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have the following very simple dataclass:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    value: int
```

I create an instance of the class but instead of an integer I use a string:

```
>>> test = Test('1')
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'str'>
```

What I actually want is a forced conversion to the datatype i defined in the class defintion:

```
>>> test = Test('1')
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

Do I have to write the `__init__` method manually or is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The type hint of dataclass attributes is never obeyed in the sense that types are enforced or checked. Mostly static type checkers like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org) are expected to do this job, Python won't do it at runtime, as it never does.

If you want to add manual type checking code, do so in the [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    value: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not isinstance(self.value, int):
            raise ValueError('value not an int')
            # or self.value = int(self.value)
```

You could use [`dataclasses.fields(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) to get a tuple of [`Field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.Field) objects which specify the field and the type and loop over that to do this for each field automatically, without writing it for each one individually.

```
def __post_init__(self):
    for field in dataclasses.fields(self):
        value = getattr(self, field.name)
        if not isinstance(value, field.type):
            raise ValueError(f'Expected {field.name} to be {field.type}, '
                             f'got {repr(value)}')
            # or setattr(self, field.name, field.type(value))
```

Comment: thanks! this not exactly what i wanted (exception instead of conversion), but thanks to your suggestion I was able to find a solution

Comment: I would err on the side of exceptions instead of implicit conversion, but I did give you the conversion alternative in the comments there…

Comment: oops, didnt see that last comment!

Comment: An alternative [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622643/) using a decorator instead of `__post_init__`.

Comment: Don't do this with dataclasses you should prefer attrs  for these kind of jobs...
https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/

Comment: This was a nice workaroung for me until using `from __future__ import annotations`. Then field.type becomes a string, which prevents it from being used as an argument in `isinstance` or as a type converter in `field.type()`. I will switch to attrs and their explicit converters now.

Answer (score 23):

It's easy to achieve by using [pydantic.validate_arguments](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validation_decorator/)

Just use the `validate_arguments` decorator in your dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import validate_arguments


@validate_arguments
@dataclass
class Test:
    value: int
```

Then try your demo, the 'str type' 1 will convert from `str` to `int`

```
>>> test = Test('1')
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

If you pass the truly wrong type, it will raise exception

```
>>> test = Test('apple')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Test
value
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Comment: It's in beta as of April 2021, but it looks amazing!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It worked as expected!

Comment: One caveat with `dataclass` and `validate_arguments`: Together they seem to break `classmethod`. I.e. defining a `@classmethod` factory function raises exception `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable` only when `@validate_arguments` is applied to the class

Answer (score 16):

You could achieve this using the `__post_init__` method:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    value : int

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.value = int(self.value)
```

This method is called following the `__init__` method

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing

Answer (score 8):

With Python [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), the alternative is to use the [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method, as pointed out in other answers:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    value: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.value = int(self.value)
```

```
>>> test = Test("42")
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

Or you can use the [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/) package, which allows you to easily set [converters](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#converters):

```
@attr.define
class Test:
    value: int = attr.field(converter=int)
```

```
>>> test = Test("42")
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

You can use the [`cattrs`](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/) package, that does conversion based on the type annotations in [`attr` classes and dataclasses](https://cattrs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structuring.html#attrs-classes-and-dataclasses), if your data comes from a mapping instead:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Test:
    value: int
```

```
>>> test = cattrs.structure({"value": "42"}, Test)
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

[Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) will automatically do conversion based on the types of the fields in the [model](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#basic-model-usage):

```
class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    value: int
```

```
>>> test = Test(value="42")
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the easy answer is to just do the conversion yourself in your own `__init__()`. I do this because I want my objects `frozen=True`.

For the type validation, Pydandic claims to do it, but I haven't tried it yet: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/

Comment: after the conversion, how can you assign the converted value since it is frozen!?

Answer (score 1):

You could use descriptor-typed field:

```
class IntConversionDescriptor:

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = "_" + name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self._name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self._name, int(value))


@dataclass
class Test:
    value: IntConversionDescriptor = IntConversionDescriptor()
```

```
>>> test = Test(value=1)
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>

>>> test = Test(value="12")
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>

test.value = "145"
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>

test.value = 45.12
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: I believe the type annotation needs to be fixed. when run within an IDE, looks like it gives me warning when I try to pass it like `value=1` into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `setattr`?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass()
class Test:
    value: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        for field in fields(self):
            setattr(self, field.name, field.type(getattr(self, field.name)))
```

Which yields the required result:

```
>>> test = Test('1')
>>> type(test.value)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but thats pretty much exactly what deceze suggested almost 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic type-conversion [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), declared in `descriptors.py`:

```py
import sys


class TypeConv:

    __slots__ = (
        '_name',
        '_default_factory',
    )

    def __init__(self, default_factory=None):
        self._default_factory = default_factory

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self._name = "_" + name
        if self._default_factory is None:
            # determine default factory from the type annotation
            tp = owner.__annotations__[name]
            if isinstance(tp, str):
                # evaluate the forward reference
                base_globals = getattr(sys.modules.get(owner.__module__, None), '__dict__', {})
                idx_pipe = tp.find('|')
                if idx_pipe != -1:
                    tp = tp[:idx_pipe].rstrip()
                tp = eval(tp, base_globals)
            # use `__args__` to handle `Union` types
            self._default_factory = getattr(tp, '__args__', [tp])[0]

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self._name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self._name, self._default_factory(value))
```

Usage in `main.py` would be like:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
from descriptors import TypeConv


@dataclass
class Test:
    value: int | str = TypeConv()


test = Test(value=1)
print(test)

test = Test(value='12')
print(test)

# watch out: the following assignment raises a `ValueError`
try:
    test.value = '3.21'
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
Test(value=1)
Test(value=12)
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.21'
```

Note that while this *does* work for other simple types, it does not handle conversions for certain types - such as `bool` or `datetime` - as normally expected.

If you are OK with using third-party libraries for this, I have come up with a (de)serialization library called the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) that can perform type conversion as needed, but only when `fromdict()` is called:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Test(JSONWizard):
    value: int
    is_active: bool


test = Test.from_dict({'value': '123', 'is_active': 'no'})
print(repr(test))

assert test.value == 123
assert not test.is_active

test = Test.from_dict({'is_active': 'tRuE', 'value': '3.21'})
print(repr(test))

assert test.value == 3
assert test.is_active
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of converting numpy arrays to lists and this did the job:

```
def fix_field_types(self):
    for key, value in self.asdict().items():
        field = self.__dataclass_fields__[key]
        if not field.type == type(value):
            new_value = field.type.__call__(value)
            self.__setattr__(field.name, new_value)
```