# How to validate namedtuple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, namedtuple

I had namedtuple variable which represents version of application (its number and type). But i want and some restriction to values:

```
Version = namedtuple("Version", ["app_type", "number"])
version = Version("desktop") # i want only "desktop" and "web" are valid app types
version = Version("deskpop") # i want to protect from such mistakes
```

My solution for now is primitive class with no methods:

```
class Version:
    def __init__(self, app_type, number):
        assert app_type in ('desktop', 'web')

        self.app_type = app_type
        self.number = number
```

Is it pythonic? Is it overkill?

Comment: Why are you assigning `Version` to a namedtuple, and also declaring a class with that same variable?

Comment: @JacobIRR I assume the class version is an *alternative* implementation

Comment: If the only two valid app types are `"desktop"` and `"web"` consider making an `Enum` class to specify that.  Then instead of passing a raw string into your `namedtuple` you pass in a `AppType` enum.

Comment: A class seems fine. If you were using a namedtuple to save memory, just use `__slots__`

Comment: I agree with @juanpa — class is the way to do it. If you're using Python 3.7+, consider using a `dataclass` — see [Validating detailed types in python dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563546/validating-detailed-types-in-python-dataclasses).

Comment: I would avoid using `assert` in this case.  Raising a `ValueError` seems more appropriate here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/945135/10863327

Comment: However you do it, consider making `app_type` and [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#module-enum) to limit the permissible values.

Comment: People ask "is this Pythonic?" instead of asking "is this good OOD?" now. Sigh.

Comment: @spinkus I think "pythonic" can be treated as "good OOD in python"

Comment: Not sure that's possible ... ;).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `enum.Enum`, and `typing.NamedTuple` instead of `collections.namedtuple`:

Maybe something like this:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import enum

class AppType(enum.Enum):
    desktop = 0
    web = 1

class Version(NamedTuple):
    app: AppType


v0 = Version(app=AppType.desktop)
v1 = Version(app=AppType.web)

print(v0, v1)
```

#### output:

```
Version(app=<AppType.desktop: 0>) Version(app=<AppType.web: 1>)
```

A undefined `AppType` raises an `AttributeError`:

```
v2 = Version(app=AppType.deskpoop)
```

#### output:

```
AttributeError: deskpoop
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding use enums. I'll accept this)

Comment: It may not be important, but using `Version(app=AppType.deskpoop)`, similar to what was done in first two examples, would have resulted in an `AttributeError: deskpoop`. The `NameError` is occurring because you used `Version(AppType=deskpoop)` in the third example.

Comment: Thank you for that @martineau, good catch. I think it is important, I modified my answer. Incidentally, the `AttributeError` message raised by `Enum` is rather terse: the traceback is okay, but the message could contain the name of the class it was raised from.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with the accepted answer above, since the validation is actually not done in the NamedTuple class itself, but in external class with **extra call**, and so it is still possible to do invalid initialisation of *Version* instance with default constructor:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import enum

class AppType(enum.Enum):
    desktop = 0
    web = 1

class Version(NamedTuple):
    app: AppType

>>> v=Version(42)
>>> print(v)

   Version(app=42)

>>> v2=Version('whatever you want')
>>> print(v2)

   Version(app='whatever you want')
```

I haven't found a way to overload or at least to disable the default NamedTuple constructor, to prevent invalid initialisation((

The workaround I'm using - creating an alternative constructor(s), which implement validation. but again nothing prevents 'user' to create invalid object using default NamedTuple constructor:

```
class Version2(NamedTuple):
    app_type : str
    
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, app_value: str):
        assert app_value in ('desktop', 'web')
        return cls(app_value) 

>>> Version2.new('web')
Version2(app_type='web')

>>> Version2.new('tablet')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 6, in new
AssertionError

>>> Version2('whatever you want')
Version2(app_type='whatever you want')
```