# Any way to get all possible Python class variables, including ones without values?

Tags: python, class, validation, member

I'm creating a class to represent a query, like this:

```
class Query:
    height: int
    weight: int
    age: int
    name: str
    is_alive: bool = True
```

As you can see, some variables start off initialized with defaults, others don't.

I want to implement chainable setters like so

```
    def of_height(self, height):
        self.height = height
        return self

    def with_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return self

    ...
```

The goal is to call this from several places in the project like so:

```
q = Query()
q.of_height(175).with_name("Alice")
```

Then I want to call a `q.validate()` that checks if any fields were *not* set, before calling an API with this query.

I can't figure out a way to dynamically check all *possible* variables, set or not, to check if any were left unset. Ideally, I don't want to implement a `validate` that has to be changed every time I add a possible query dimension in this class.

Comment: The answers in the [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398022/674039) are not helpful here because it won't include uninitialized ones.

Comment: There is quite a lot of information [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563546/validating-detailed-types-in-python-dataclasses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [variable annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-variable-annotation) collected during class body execution are stored in an `__annotations__` attribute which you can use.

```
>>> Query.__annotations__
{'height': int, 'weight': int, 'age': int, 'name': str, 'is_alive': bool}
```

This is documented in the [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) under the "Custom classes" section.

Usually, you would not access this attribute directly but use [`inspect.get_annotations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.get_annotations) instead, which provides a few conveniences.

Comment: Is there a way to make this inheritance friendly? If I have `class Query2(Query):`, can I get the annotations from both?

Comment: @tdelaney Hmm, I guess that `ChainMap(*[inspect.get_annotations(Q) for Q in Query2.__mro__])` might be sufficient?

Comment: This is perfect! This project is not on 3.10 yet unfortunately, but `__annotations__` works well. Also worth mentioning for posterity that it does work on class instances, which is what I needed. As @tdelaney showed in their answer, `hasattr` or `getattr` is needed to actually make use of the annotation string names returned.

Answer (score 3):

Following on @wim's solution, it would be desirable to get annotations from `self` so that a `validate` method will work with subclasses. Following is an implementation using `inspect.get_annotations` - but note that its a 3.10 feature.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

import inspect
import itertools

class Query:
    height: int
    weight: int
    age: int
    name: str
    is_alive: bool = True

class Query2(Query):
    foo: int

    def get_annotated_attrs(self):
        return set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(inspect.get_annotations(Q).keys() for Q in self.__class__.__mro__))

    def validate(self):
        for name in self.get_annotated_attrs():
            if not hasattr(self, name):
                return False
        return True

q2 = Query2()
print(q2.get_annotated_attrs())
print(q2.validate())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of something like this

```py
import inspect

class Query:
    height: int
    weight: int
    age: int
    name: str
    is_alive: bool = True
    
    avilable_dimentions = ['height', 'weight', 'age', 'name', 'is_alive']

    def of_height(self, height):
        self.height = height
        return self

    def with_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return self
    
    def validate(self):
        not_defined = []
        for dim in self.avilable_dimentions:
            try:
                eval(f'self.{dim}')
            except:
                not_defined.append(dim)
        
        if not_defined:
            raise Exception(f'Missing dimentions {not_defined}') 
        return self

class Query2(Query):
    height2: int
    weight2: int

    avilable_dimentions = Query.avilable_dimentions + ['height2', 'weight2']
    

q = Query2()
q = q.of_height(175).with_name("Alice").validate()
```